# error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to double

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;


// This program will estimate the cost to paint a room in your house

public class PaintJobEstimator {

    // square feet per one gallon of paint.
    public static final double AREA_PER_GALLON = 112.0; 

    // hours of labor needed to paint AREA_PER_GALLON square feet.
    public static final double HOURS_PER_UNIT_AREA = 8.0;

    // charge to customer for one hour of labor.
    public static final double LABOR_COST_PER_HOUR = 35.0;

    // main declares a Scanner that is passed to
    // the input methods. main also controls the
    // order of calculations.
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

        // How many square feet do we need to paint?
        double sqft = getInput( keyboard, 
                       "Enter the number of square feet: " );

        // How much does a gallon of paint cost?
        double gallonCost = getInput( keyboard, 
                       "Enter the price of a gallon of paint: " );        
        ////////////////////////////////////////
        // Calculate the cost of this paint job.
        ////////////////////////////////////////

        // First, how many gallons of paint do we need?
        int numGallons = calculateGallons( sqft );

        // How long will the job take?
        double hoursLabor = calculateHours( sqft );

        // How much will the paint cost?
        double paintCost = calculatePaintCost( numGallons, gallonCost );

        // How much will the labor cost?
        double laborCost = calculateLaborCost( hoursLabor );

        // What's the total bill?
        double totalCost = calculateTotalCost( paintCost, laborCost );

        // Print the results.
        generateReport( sqft, gallonCost, numGallons, hoursLabor, 
                        paintCost, laborCost, totalCost);

    }

    public static double getInput( Scanner input, String prompt ) {
        System.out.print( prompt );
        while ( !input.hasNextDouble() ) {
            input.nextLine(); // get rid of bad input.
            System.out.print( prompt );
        }
        double inValue = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine(); // clear the input line.
        return inValue;
    }


    // Your methods go here:

    // calculateGallons
    public static int calculateGallons( double sqft ) {
        // TO DO return correct value
        return (int)Math.ceil(sqft / AREA_PER_GALLON);
    } 

    // calculateHours
    public static double calculateHours( double sqft ) {
        // TO DO return correct value
        return sqft / 14;
    }

    // TO DO: calculatePaintCost
    public static double calculatePaintCost (int numGallons, double gallonCost){
        return numGallons * gallonCost;
    }

    // TO DO: calculateLaborCost (Hours * Labor/hr)
    public static double calculateLaborCost( double hoursLabor ){
        return hoursLabor * LABOR_COST_PER_HOUR;
    }    
    // TO DO: calculateTotalCost
    public static double calculateTotalCost( double paintCost, double laborCost ){
        return paintCost + laborCost;
    }

    // To Do: generateReport
    public static double generateReport(double sqft,  double gallonCost, int numGallons, double hoursLabor, double paintCost, double laborCost, double totalCost) {
        return  System.out.print("To paint" + sqft + "square feet, with"); 
                System.out.print("paint that costs" + gallonCost + "per gallon,"); 
                System.out.print("you will need" + numGallons + "gallons of paint"); 
                System.out.print("and" + hoursLabor + "hours of labor."); 
                System.out.print("The cost of the paint is: " + paintCost ); 
                System.out.print("The cost of the labor is: "+ laborCost); 
                System.out.print("The total cost of the job is: " + totalCost); 
        System.out.println();
    }




}
```

I am having with the generateReport method, i don't know how to return it properly.  i keep getting the error

```
PaintJobEstimator.java:99: error: incompatible types: void cannot be              converted to double      
    return  System.out.print("To paint" + sqft + "square feet, with"); 
                            ^
```

what am i doing wrong. or am i just completely missing the point.  I am new at this and really need help, i don't want to get the answer but if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.print()` returns no value; it has a return type of `void`.

In order to rewrite this without any errors, change it to something like this:

```
public static void generateReport(double sqft,  double gallonCost, int numGallons, double hoursLabor, double paintCost, double laborCost, double totalCost) {
            System.out.print("To paint" + sqft + "square feet, with"); 
            System.out.print("paint that costs" + gallonCost + "per gallon,"); 
            System.out.print("you will need" + numGallons + "gallons of paint"); 
            System.out.print("and" + hoursLabor + "hours of labor."); 
            System.out.print("The cost of the paint is: " + paintCost ); 
            System.out.print("The cost of the labor is: "+ laborCost); 
            System.out.print("The total cost of the job is: " + totalCost); 
            System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print(...)` prints given objects to output.
`return` is used to pass values to the caller of the function, in this case, your `main` method. Since your `generateReport` method is of type `double`, you have to return some `double` value. If you don't want to return anything, then your method should be `void`.

`System.out.print(...)` for instance, is a `void` function.